# How to create a custom method for the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, irb, rails-console

When I'm using the Rails console in Ubuntu for a long session I define the `clear` method:

`def clear; system 'clear' end`

So when my console is getting dirty the only thing I have to do is type `clear` and the console gets cleared.

I would like to use this function without to re-type it every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried Ctrl-L and Ctrl-K?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put it in the `~/.irbrc` file. It gets loaded every time you run `irb` or `rails console`. The Rails console is just `irb` with your Rails application environment loaded.

Find more infos about `irb` here: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html#S2

Comment: Link is dead.  Here is an alternative:  http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html#S2

Answer (score 1):

Put this function to `~/.irbrc`

```
def clear
  system 'clear'
end
```

Then it'll be available when you run irb.

Answer (score 1):

In case you like to define your console helpers in the realm of your rails-project-directory, there's another interesting approach: You can extend the [`Rails::ConsoleMethods`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html)-module, which holds well-known and handy console-stuff like `app`, `helper`, `controller` etc... Here's one easy way to do this:

Just add a module to your `lib`-directory that holds your custom console helpers and apply it to `Rails::ConsoleMethods` via mixin prepending - e.g.:

```rb
# Extending Rails::ConsoleMethods with custom console helpers
module CustomConsoleHelpers

  # ** APP SPECIFIC CONSOLE UTILITIES ** #

  # User by login or last
  def u(login=nil)
    login ? User.find_by_login!(login) : User.last
  end

  # Fav test user to massage in the console
  def honk
    User.find_by_login!("Honk")
  end

  # ...

  # ** GENERAL CONSOLE UTILITIES ** #

  # Helper to open the source location of a specific 
  # method definition in your editor, e.g.:
  #
  #   show_source_for(User.first, :full_name)
  #
  # 'inspired' (aka copy pasta) by 'https://pragmaticstudio.com/tutorials/view-source-ruby-methods' 
  def show_source_for(object, method)
    location = object.method(method).source_location
    `code --goto #{location[0]}:#{location[1]}` if location
    location
  end

  # ...
end

require 'rails/console/helpers'
Rails::ConsoleMethods.send(:prepend, CustomConsoleHelpers)
```

This works for me like a charm. Further alternatives to this approach (which I didn't test) would be to either put the above in an initializer (like [here](https://selleo.com/til/posts/llq0l8t8cm-extend-ruby-on-rails-console-with-custom-methods)) - or to extend `Rails::ConsoleMethods` in `config/application.rb` instead - e.g. like this (found [here](https://www.dailysmarty.com/posts/how-to-add-rails-console-helper-methods) and [here](https://opensoul.org/2012/11/08/add-helper-methods-to-your-rails-console/)):

```rb
console do
  require 'custom_console_helpers'
  Rails::ConsoleMethods.send :include, CustomConsoleHelpers
end
```